# Open Excel file in perl and print row count

Tags: perl, excel, count, row

I am using Win32::OLE module to open an excel file and get row count. The problem is when i hard code excel file path it works fine but when i dynamically pass path it throw an error saying that "cant call method workbooks on unblessed reference". Please find the below sample code.

```
use OLE;
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Excel';

my $xapp= Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Excel.Application')
            or do { Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application', 'Quit')};
    $xapp->{'Visible'} = 0;
    my $file='excel.xlsx';
    my $fileName="c:/users/mujeeb/desktop/".$file;
    print $fileName;
    my $wkb = $xapp->Workbooks->Open($fileName); //here i am getting error coz i am passing dynamic fileName;
    my $wks = $wkb->Worksheets('Sheet1');
    my $Tot_Rows=$wks->UsedRange->Rows->{'Count'}; 
    print $Tot_Rows."\n";
    $xapp->close;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use backslashes in the filename.

The filename is given to excel and excel won't understand forward slashes. Perl does not convert them because Perl doesn't know the string is a file.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that there exists a method named as `Open`? Because I don't see it in the documentation of `Win32::OLE`. Also you must add `use Win32::OLE;` in your code.

Comment: Win32::OLE won't meantion any methods that are defined in an OLE interface, nor can it do that because the method found dynamically at runtime.

Comment: one more question will this Module work if excel is not installed on the machine?

Comment: @user1480318: you shouldn't ask questions in comments. But to answer your question: no, you can't access Excel with `Win32::OLE` when there is no Excel.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this line of code to change the path into readable path for OLE:

```
my $file='excel.xlsx';
my $fileName="c:/users/mujeeb/desktop/".$file;
$fileName=~s/[\/]/\\/g;
print $fileName;
```

outputs:

```
c:\\users\\mujeeb\\desktop\\excel.xlsx
```